# Problem 3.10 in Fulton's Algebraic Curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The problem asks to prove that every irreducible affine plane curve $f(x,y)=0$
has finitely many multiple (or singular) points. One possible solution is to say that at least one of $f_x,f_y$ is different than zero (these are partial derivatives) and so the set of singular points is the affine variety of $\mathbb{A}^2$ given by $V(f,f_x,f_y)$. Since $f$ is irreducible and assuming that $f_x \neq 0$, the sequence $f,f_x$ is
$k[x,y]$-regular and so $\dim k[x,y]/(f,f_x,f_y) = 0$. This then implies that $V(f,f_x,f_y)$ is a zero dimensional affine variety and so it must be a finite collection of points.

The issue with Fulton is that he has not introduced dimensions yet, and so i wonder whether there is an alternative, possibly more geometric solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think proposition 2 in §1.6 of Fulton's book might help you: Let $F, G$ be polynomials in $k[X, Y]$ with no common factors. Then $V(F, G)$ is a finite set of points. In your case: $V(f, f_x, f_y) \subseteq V(f, f_x)$. If we assume $f_x \neq 0$ than $f, f_x$ have no common factors as $f$ is irreducible. So we can apply the proposition.

Comment: That's a nice argument indeed. Thanks.